# send data from ajax to controller codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to send data from javascript to function in controller with ajax. But ajax wont send. I post my code below:

**In javascript function**

```
var day = $(obj).text();
var base_url = $('#baseurl').val();

$.ajax({
    url: base_url + "Front_end_controller/eventi",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {date: day},
    success:function(result) {
        alert(result); // alert your date variable value here
    }
});
```

**In controller**

```
public function eventi()
{
    $day = $this->input->post('date');
    var_dump($day);
}
```

Comment: have you tried `var_dump($_POST)` sometime it act weird

Comment: return NULL in the controller's function.

Comment: Also, AJAX won't send any null data, make sure that your  `day` variable is set.

Comment: can you find any error in console? maybe url will be wrong.

Comment: `console.log(day)`  or `alert(day)` and check

Comment: the var_dump($_POST) return "array(0) { }"

Comment: Also check your network in for request is making or not, if making then what is header, request, response

Comment: result of console.log(day) is 17

Comment: and its correct

Comment: I add this code.

 success:function(result) {
  alert(result); // alert your date variable value here
}

and this return alert with the number selected.

Comment: what is this `Front_end_controller` ?? **controller name never comes with `_controller` sufix**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. see if it works. Just using "type" instead of "method"

```
var day = $(obj).text();
var base_url = $('#baseurl').val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: base_url + "Front_end_controller/eventi",
    data: {date: day},
    success:function(result) {
        alert(result); // alert your date variable value here
    },
    error:function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
});
```

And in your controler :

```
public function eventi()
{
    $day = $this->input->post('date');
    if(!empty($day)) 
    {
        echo $day;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No Data";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you miss something. Add the error callback in the ajax function:

```
var day = $(obj).text();
var base_url = $('#baseurl').val();

$.ajax({
    url: base_url + "Front_end_controller/eventi",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {date: day},
    success:function(result) {
        alert(result); // alert your date variable value here
    },
    error:function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Now, check your console for the error.
It could be an error on the route too (check the `/application/config/routes.php` too).

Comment: Have you tried to print something and check if content is shown from "success" or "error"? What happen if you try to pass something using get? Can you reach the page manually and check what is printed out?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try `echo` instead of `var_dump`. Also, check that the input is actually there and echo a message saying so if it is not.

```
public function eventi()
{
    $day = $this->input->post('date');
    if(isset($day)) //not NULL
    {
        echo $day;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No Data";
    }
}
```

You could also use a ternary to decide what to echo. This line produces the same result as the if/else statement above.

```
echo isset($day) ? $day : "No Data";
```

Comment: yep. the result is "No data" so ajax dont send data to controller.

Comment: Could be because `$(obj).text();` doesn't return anything in your javascript.

Comment: well the '$(obj).text();' return the number selected in console. I use that for get the number select when i click on link href
'<a href="'.base_url().'calendario/eventi" onclick="clickfunc(this)">'

Comment: And you are certain that the var `day` is being set correctly? Have you used your browser's dev tools to see what the ajax call is sending to the server?